# What is the maximum delay in getting http response?

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection, session-timeout, connection-timeout

I am sending a request over http. Connection time out and read time out are set to 30000ms. What is the maximum time after which i receive a response?
Is it combined read + connection timeouts ?
My doubt is when does read timeout start, after acquiring the connection or from the time we start to try establishing the connection?
Will the connection be terminated after the configured connection time out even is connection is established?

The difference between the two timeouts are clear but exactly when they are taken into consideration is not clear for me.

```
con.setConnectTimeout(30000); 
con.setReadTimeout(30000);
```

Comment: @DimaSan The other question does not mention when exactly both the timeouts comes into picture. It explains the difference between the two timeouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connectTimeout` limits the time that connection establishement can take, while `readConnectionTimeout` says how long you can wait between datapackets (consecutive reads) **after connection is established**.

So first, you try to establish the connection and limits that process to `connectTimeout`. After connection establishement, you read incoming data using `readConnectionTimeout`.

The second one, **will  not** limit the overall time of data reading operation. The total read time can be no longer then `packets_to_be_send * readConnectionTimeout`

Comment: Should the 'connectTimeout' be greater than 'packets_to_be_send * readConnectionTimeout'. Will the connection time out come into picture once connection is established?

Comment: This does not matter as those timeouts are mutually exclusive - first you try to establish connection (TCP controll) - here `connectionTimeout` takes the place. After connection is established, the actual application data is read - this is where `readConnectionsTimeout` comes in. As connection is already established, `connectTimeout` has no meaning anymore.

Comment: @DarshanGopalR You have pinpointed the issue here in (edited) comment - no, after connection is established `connectionTimeout` is not taken into any consideration anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification